# Networking problem in dorms

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

So I recently got a headless Server box running WHS with a E2000 router w/dd-wrt big for media and whatnots.  But I am having some trouble getting everything working the way I want it to. 
1) main problem: My router cant seem to connect to the ethernet port in my room.
2) Cant get internet on my server to run updates

I am having to pick between connecting to the server or to the internet <- pisses me off

NOtes: the internet in my room require a username and pw for internet connection (entered through the browser)

Comment: Depending on how it keeps track of what is logged in, you might try to authenticate with your computer, then connect the router with it set to use the computer's MAC address.

Comment: It doesnt seem to use a MAC authenicate.  Do you know if dd-wrt have a login mode for ethernet that require logins?